# How to keep description of google code project under version control?

Tags: google-code

Google hosting keeps wiki pages under version control.
How to keep description of google code project under version control?

'Description of google code project' supports wiki syntax and rendered to main page http://name_of_project.googlecode.com

Comment: Trying to include wiki page content to project description, but have troubles with it